# Locust cannot maintain Session in HTTPS

Tags: python, locust

I have a Locustfile in which I perform authentication, like so:

```
  def on_start(self):
    response = self.client.get('/login-page/url')
    csrftoken = response.cookies['csrftoken']
    credentials = {
      "username":"username",
      "password":"password"
    }
    self.client.post("/login-page/url'", data=credentials, headers={'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken})
```

Since Locust suports cookies, in all subsequent requests/tasks I should have my "user" logged in.

My Locustfile is basically made of tasks like this one:

```
  @task
  def some-task(self):
    with self.client.get("/some/path", allow_redirects=False, catch_response=True) as response:
      if response.status_code == 302:
        response.failure("You were redirected")
```

Here, after the request is sent I check for errors using the status code. If it's 302 that means the user was redirected because the authentication failed.

All tasks are running without errors ("Fail" column in the GUI) except in one of my websites which uses HTTPS.

I tried changing to HTTP, with the same site, and the tasks worked again.

I looked through Locust's docs and in SO but until now no proper answers. I'd really like to know why this happens and how can I overcome this.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the "verify" option set to "False" like here: https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: Maybe double check the response from the POST to see that you were properly logged in? What you’re doing should work.

Comment: Hi @Cyberwiz, I had done that. In the HTTPS scenario the response was a "not found" HTML page I have in my framework (which is Django). So, for some reason, with HTTPS it seems Locust is unable to do the redirection after a succesful authentication, and instead gives me a "not found" page.